# How to disable concurrent build in Wercker

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, wercker

Since some months, Wercker add a feature to execute 2 concurrent builds.
The problem is that during the build, it report tests results in Sonar and Sonar can handle multiple reporting at the same time. That why, I would like to disable this feature. I found nothing in the documentation to do that.

Do you have a solution to disable concurrent build feature?

Comment: Which version of the SonarQube you use? If you upgrade it to 5.2, then the problem will be resolved by SonarQube server (this version introduced [background tasks](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Background+Tasks))

Comment: I'm using sonarqube 4.5.2. And I can't upgrade regarding compatibilities of certain plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an employee from wercker. We've had the concurrent builds from the beginning, currently the default is 2. It is not possible for a user to change the concurrency.

However Wercker can manually change the concurrency for a user account to 1 by contacting the Wercker support.

Comment: Dammm, I wasn't prepared for that :D. Thank you for the answer and for Wercker services :)